# how to solve this problem sum of the element of list in triangle format

Tags: python, list, sum

I was attempting the sum of elements of the list. where I have to add the adjacent elements of the list and create a new list and repeat the process until I have the last element which will be the answer. I am able to solve the list of lengths less than 5 but I am not able to generalize the solution for any given list. Help me to solve this problem. below is my starting code:
here is the example;
[general example of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hxtbp.png)

```
lst=[]
n=int(input())

for i in range(0,n):
 num = int(input())

  lst.append(num)
 print(lst)
 sum1=[]
for i in range(1,len(lst)):
  sum=i+i+1
  sum1.append(sum)

print(sum1)
```

Comment: @MSH OP asked for sum of adjacent digits that is NOT Pascal's triangle

Comment: I know. Pascal's triangle has the same logic. So instead of directly handing the answer I thought point them to a useful direction would be better. :)

Comment: this is actually directly related to Pascal's triangle, the result is the sum of numbers weighted with Pascal's coefficients (e.g, for 4 numbers: a*1+b*3+c*3+d*1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple understandable function:

```
def solve(seq):
    
    while len(seq) > 1:
        res = []
        for i in range(len(seq) - 1):
            res.append(seq[i] + seq[i+1])
        print(res)
        seq = res
        
    return res[0]

solve([1,2,3,4])
```

The idea is to find adjacent sums and store in a new list. Keep doing till length becomes 1.

Some higher order function magic can be added to this if the logic becomes clear to someone.

Answer (score 1):

The following seems reasonably simple:

```
n = int(input())
lst = [int(input()) for _ in range(n)]

while len(lst) > 1:
    lst[:] = map(sum, zip(lst, lst[1:]))  # all sums of neighbours
    print(lst)


# Output for 1 2 3 4
# [3, 5, 7]
# [8, 12]
# [20]
```

Some docs:

- [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip)
- [`map`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map)
- [`sum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum)

Answer (score 0):

Given 2 lists of equal length you could do this:

```
M = [1,2,3]
N = [5,6,7]
print(*map(sum, zip(M,N)))
```